# Car cranks but won't start, but not all the time

Tags: cranks-wont-run

I went to the store yesterday with my car (Hyundai Accent 2012), and when I went to go back home, the car was cranking but not starting. I thought it was a battery issue.

Took the keys off, called a friend to get the battery boosted, but after 2-3 minutes, I wanted to try again and the car started. Went back home fine. Once I got home, stopped the engine, tried to start it again, and it worked perfectly fine. The car was cranking for 1 or 2 seconds and was starting just fine.

No idea what the issue was. A friend of mine told me that if it was a battery issue, the card would not have started as well as it did. Don't know if that's true, he's not a pro mechanic guy.

Then this morning, wanted to start the car, and didn't worked again.

One thing I have noticed is that the car radio/clock is resetting almost everytime I start the car. It happened earlier this week, but the car was doing fine so I haven't bothered to check much, and just reconfigured the radio.

Wonder what all this can be?
I've heard that if it was a starter issue, the car would just not crank at all. And if the battery was dead, same thing.

Any suggestions?
The car has around 100k kilometers on the ODO. Again, it's a Hyundai Accent 2012. When the car started yesterday (when at the store), everything was feeling perfectly normal. I was not hearing weird noises or anything, and no unknown lights were on in the dashboard of the car.

Can it be a spark plug that needs to be replaced maybe?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This really sounds like it could be a battery issue. If the battery is the original battery from when new, it should be about due for one (usual new car battery life span is about 5 years).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turns out I just boosted it and the car started immediately and the cranking sound was slower before boosting it. I will check for a new battery :) Thanks again!

Comment: Take your current battery to a parts store and get it load tested. They can tell you how much life is in the thing.